# g_main_loop_run() freeze the window

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, gstreamer

I am trying to create a video player in C# using the functions imported from the GStreamer library by Pinvoke. It's looking nice so far, but if I add `g_main_loop_run(loop);` my C# application freezes and I just can't click any button or move my window.

I think that the problem may involve `gmaincontext`, but I don't know exactly what the problem is or how to resolve it.

Here is my C++ code in my library:

```
GstElement *pipeline; 

void seek_to_pos(double position) { 
    gint64 len; 
    gst_element_query_duration(pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &len); 
    gst_element_seek_simple(pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, len*position); 
} 

void play_file(char* path_to_file, void* hwnd_ptr_of_window){ 
    gst_init(NULL, NULL); 
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)hwnd_ptr_of_window; 
    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE); 

    pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "player"); 
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pipeline), "uri", path_to_file, NULL); 

    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), (guintptr)hwnd); 

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING); 
    g_main_loop_run(loop);//problem 
}
```

Without the `g_main_loop_run(loop);` string, all works fine, but of course I need it for some another things.

Also, I already know that I need to run `GMainLoop` in a 
different thread to not block my C# application's event loop but I don't know exactly how I can do it.

So I need a code sample or link which describes how I can do it right. Thanks!

Comment: Irrelevant point: GSteamer is actually written in C, not C++

Comment: Probably not really a GStreamer related question. Look at your platform threading support and read on how to spawn and control threads in your application. Alternatively you can also skip the main loop line and instead you application can take the job that is being done there - like querying the pipeline's bus for messages - that is what you are most likely interested in.